# Convert Text on database mysql and output them in pdf file

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, character-encoding, export-to-pdf

column address in database type text
I write code:

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($addr,'sjis-win','utf-8');
```

and ouptut `$string` in pdf file export. My machine text ok, but japan machine character space display `"*"`.
please help me fix!

Comment: Is the string being received into PHP correctly (make sure that you set the character set of your database connection appropriately)?

Comment: You're not telling us which tool you're using to create the PDF, nor which font to display the Japanese characters. Maybe you're using a font that doesn't know how to draw Japanese glyphs.

Comment: my database connection set encoding: utf8.
I use FPDF export pdf file.
column address type text. example: 茨城県 牛久市 ひたち野東4-25-43
when I query get address put in pdf file, japan machine display text:茨城県*牛久市*ひたち野東4-25-43. space display = "*".

Comment: What about a workaround?

`$string = str_replace("*", " ", $stringwithasterisks);`

Problem is that you can't display asterisks because it'll be always converted into spaces :(

Comment: @Pablo-BisonNetworks- this is a bad idea of yours. The `$string` can contain an * which means something other than a space...